# how to bring back this format of wordpress options when making a blog post?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg, wordpress-shortcode

1. I would like to have this Format option in my wordpress when i make new post
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KA1aT.jpg)
2. Now i have different options in my wordpress post settings[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXwa6.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Please try "Classic Editor" plugin.
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The format of a text block is controlled by the different blocks in your view with Gutenberg. If you want to work without Gutenberg, you have to deactivate Gutenberg for your post type.

```
add_filter('use_block_editor_for_post_type', '__return_false', 10);
```

You can add this code to your theme's functions.php file or in a plugin. This will disable the Gutenberg editor for all post types and restore the classic editor.